# Copying multiple ansible-vault encrypted files to remote server

Tags: ansible

I have to deploy up to a hundred sensitive files to a remote server. These files are encrypted using ansible-vault so I can keep everything in version control.

The related ansible structure is as follow:

```
roles/
    app/
        tasks/
            main.yml
        files/
            foo
            bar
            ....
            foobar
```

All the files are encrypted by `ansible-vault encrypt *`. Note that the file names do not have any pattern.

I can copy the files one by one by using the below task:

```
- name: Copy encrypted foo file
  copy:
    src: "{{ role_path }}/files/foo"
    dest: "/remote/server/destination/foo"
    owner: remote-owner
    group: remote-owner
    mode: 0640
```

But obviously having one copy task per file is not an acceptable solution.

**The question is how do I write my task to copy all the ansible-vault encrypted files in a neat way?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found that ansible's copy module automatically copy recursively. Any ansible-vault encrypted files would also be decrypted.

So the solution is:

```
- name: Copy encrypted files
  copy:
    src: "{{ role_path }}/files/"
    dest: "/remote/server/destination"
    owner: remote-owner
    group: remote-owner
    mode: 0640
```

Comment: "Any ansible-vault encrypted files would also be decrypted." Use "decrypt: no" to avoid it. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html